# Guarantee an interior solution for profit maximisation

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-optimization, economics

A function $c: \mathbb{R}^K_+ \xrightarrow{} \mathbb{R}_+$ is is said to be a *cost function* if

1. The value of function $c$ at $y = \textbf{0}$ is $0$: $c(\textbf{0}) = 0$
2. $c$ is continuous on the domain $\mathbb{R}^K_+$, strictly increasing and strictly convex on $\mathbb{R}^K_{+}$
3. For any $p \in \mathbb{R}^K_{++}$, the set $B(p) = \{y \in \mathbb{R}^K_+| c(y) \leq p \cdot y\}$ is compact, the interior of $B(p)$ is nonempty.

Suppose a firm has cost function $c(\cdot)$ and $p\in \mathbb{R}^K_{++}$ is the market price. What sort of topological assumption I need to add to guarantee the existence of an **interior solution** to the profit maximisation problem?
$$
\pi (p) = \max_{y\in\mathbb{R}^K_+} \left\{ p\cdot y - c(y) \right\}
$$

**Remark 1**: From assumption (2) and (3), the existence of solution is guaranteed. Due to strict convexity, uniqueness is also guaranteed. However, the solution is probably not inside the interior of $\mathbb{R}^K_{+}$. I could not find an example for this at the moment.

**Remark 2**: My prototype cost function is $c(y) = y_1^2+y_2^2$. However, the cost is not necessarily to be additive separable.

Comment: By saying not inside the interior of $\mathbb{R}_{+}^{K}$, I guess you mean there exists $i\in\left\{1,\ldots,K\right\}$, such that at optimal choice $y^{\star}$, the $i$-th component $y_{i}^{\star}=0$? 

If so, a simple condition with $\partial c/\partial y_{i}=0$ for ANY $y$ with $y_{i}=0$ would be enough.

In that case, for any point $y$ on boundary, suppose $y_{i}=0$, consider a small increment in $y_{i}$, the profit increase by $\left(p_{i}-\partial c/\partial y_{i}\right)dy_{i}$, which is positive given $p\in\mathbb{R}_{++}^{K}$, thus $y$ is never optimal.

Comment: @Q9y5 Not being on the interior of $\mathbb{R}^K_{+}$, i.e $\mathbb{R}^K_{++}$, means being on the boundary. And yes, it implies one of the component is 0. Thanks for the suggestion. It works perfectly although I still prefer topological assumption instead of differentiability condition.